# Conditionally add a column into WebGrid

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, html, webgrid

1) I am trying to conditionally add a column into a WebGrid. And it is an anchor tag() with an img tag () inside. How can I do it?

2) The column will be displayed only if 2 parameters is not null(byte[] item.Boleto, string item.Nome_Arquivo). I set the value of both of them to null if no value is selected via sql query. Therefore, I only would need to check if both are not null, then diplay the column. But again, how do I check for it? Where can I place a conditional statement or anything like (e.g. ternary, etc) inside the WebGrid structure without ruining the rest of it?

*Let me know if any translation are needed in order to understand my issue*

The line I want to "translate" to WebGrid pattern:

```
grid.Column("", "", format:  @<a href="data:application/pdf;charset=utf-8;base64,@System.Convert.ToBase64String(item.Boleto).ToString()" target="_blank" download="@item.Nome_Arquivo" type="application/pdf" rel="noopener noreferrer"><img src="@Url.Content("~/Content/images/download_arquivo.png")" alt="down" height="16" width="16" /></a>)
```

and here is the full grid(not necessarry, but I am giving it for clarity):

```
@
@{   
@grid.GetHtml(
    alternatingRowStyle: "linha-Alternada",
    htmlAttributes: new { id = "gridListagemTituloReceber" },
    fillEmptyRows: true,
    columns: grid.Columns(


        grid.Column("", "", format:  @<a href="data:application/pdf;charset=utf-8;base64,@System.Convert.ToBase64String(item.Boleto).ToString()" target="_blank" download="@item.Nome_Arquivo" type="application/pdf" rel="noopener noreferrer"><img src="@Url.Content("~/Content/images/download_arquivo.png")" alt="down" height="16" width="16" /></a>),

        grid.Column("Tipo", ModelNames.PedidoPerfilClienteAbaTituloReceberViewModel_Tipo),
        grid.Column("Data_Emissao", ModelNames.PedidoPerfilClienteAbaTituloReceberViewModel_Data_Emissao,
            format: (item) => item.Data_Emissao == null ? "" : String.Format("{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", item.Data_Emissao)),
        grid.Column("Chave", ModelNames.PedidoPerfilClienteAbaTituloReceberViewModel_Chave),
        grid.Column("Numero_Titulo", ModelNames.PedidoPerfilClienteAbaTituloReceberViewModel_Numero_Titulo),
        grid.Column("Nota_Saida", ModelNames.PedidoPerfilClienteAbaTituloReceberViewModel_Nota_Saida),
        grid.Column("Data_Vencimento", ModelNames.PedidoPerfilClienteAbaTituloReceberViewModel_Data_Vencimento,
            format: (item) => item.Data_Vencimento == null ? "" : String.Format("{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", item.Data_Vencimento)),
        grid.Column("Valor", ModelNames.PedidoPerfilClienteAbaTituloReceberViewModel_Valor,
            format: (item) => item.Valor == null ? "" : String.Format("{0:N2}", item.Valor),
            style: "alinhado-Direita"),                
        grid.Column("Data_Baixa", ModelNames.PedidoPerfilClienteAbaTituloReceberViewModel_Data_Baixa,
            format: (item) => item.Data_Baixa == null ? "" : String.Format("{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", item.Data_Baixa)),
        grid.Column("Valor_Recebido", ModelNames.PedidoPerfilClienteAbaTituloReceberViewModel_Valor_Recebido,
            format: (item) => item.Valor_Recebido == null ? "" : String.Format("{0:N2}", item.Valor_Recebido),
            style: "alinhado-Direita"),
        grid.Column("Valor_Atualizado", ModelNames.PedidoPerfilClienteAbaTituloReceberViewModel_Valor_Atualizado,
            format: (item) => item.Valor_Atualizado == null ? "" : String.Format("{0:N2}", item.Valor_Atualizado),
            style: "alinhado-Direita"),
        grid.Column("Codigo_Especie", ModelNames.PedidoPerfilClienteAbaTituloReceberViewModel_Codigo_Especie),
        grid.Column("Descricao_Baixa", ModelNames.PedidoPerfilClienteAbaTituloReceberViewModel_Descricao_Baixa),
        grid.Column("Data_Devolucao", ModelNames.PedidoPerfilClienteAbaTituloReceberViewModel_Data_Devolucao,
            format: (item) => item.Data_Devolucao == null ? "" : String.Format("{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", item.Data_Devolucao)),
        grid.Column("Motivo_Devolucao", ModelNames.PedidoPerfilClienteAbaTituloReceberViewModel_Motivo_Devolucao)
    )
)
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
grid.Column("", "",
    @<text>
         @if (item.Boleto != null && item.Nome_Arquivo != null)
         {
            <a href="data:application/pdf;charset=utf-8;base64,@System.Convert.ToBase64String(item.Boleto).ToString()" target="_blank" download="@item.Nome_Arquivo" type="application/pdf" rel="noopener noreferrer"><img src="@Url.Content("~/Content/images/download_arquivo.png")" alt="down" height="16" width="16" /></a>
         }
     </text>),
```